# How can use DISTINCT in SQL Query for extracting records from 1 Data Extension and dumping it in another Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql

I have 1st DataExtension names "Accessories" and 2nd as "TestAccessories". I want to dump all the unique records from Accessories to TestAccessories, My query is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Customer Code], Email, Location, [Operator Code], Date, Time, [Customer Group1], GUID
FROM Accessories
```

In Accessories DE GUID is Primary key, and I want unique values from [customer code] field, the above given query is not giving me unique values.What is the other way?

I have tried the same query for finding Distinct emails but it's not giving required output.

Comment: Have you tried using just one field, the one that needs to be unique, like `SELECT DISTINCT [Customer Code] FROM Accessories`

Comment: Yes, I did try this also but it's not working as required.

Comment: I have tried it. This works for me: `SELECT DISTINCT Field as UUID
FROM dataExtension1`. The as UUID is only to match it on the field on the target data extension

Comment: GUID's are already unique fields so its of no use to filter data based on GUID.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you will get every item out of this because you use distinct over all of your fields instead of only one column.

Workaround, because i dont know the better way atm:

1. Create a DataExtension called DISTINCTCUSTOMERCODES with the field CustomerCode
2. Create an SQL Query Automation `SELECT DISTINCT [Customer Code] as CustomerCode FROM Accessories` into the new Data Extension DISTINCTCUSTOMERCODES
3. Create a Second SQL Query Activity`SELECT DISTINCT [Customer Code], Email, Location, [Operator Code], Date, Time, [Customer Group1], GUID
   FROM Accessories as acc
   INNER JOIN DISTINCTCUSTOMERCODES as dcc
   ON acc.CustomerCode= dcc.CustomerCode`
4. Create an Automation that runs those activities after each other

I know that there is a better solution for the SQL Statement. I believe (not certain) you have to do something like this. I know the Syntax is wrong on the JOIN statement atleast, feel free to correct this.

```
SELECT [Customer Code], Email, Location, [Operator Code], Date, Time, [Customer Group1], GUID
FROM Accessories as acc1
INNER JOIN Accessories as acc2
(SELECT DISTINCT [Customer Code]
FROM Accessories as acc2)
ON acc1.[Customer Code]= acc2.[Customer Code]
```

Comment: This isn't useful because I have only 1 data extension which contains records and I want to dump the data in the 2nd data extension. ('Customer Code" is a field in the data extension).

Comment: Got one mistake in one query in my workaround. Are you sure that you dont want to create a new dataextension like i Said in the workaround? It is working and i tested it aswell.

Comment: @Prisha  you need only query the  [Customer Code] filed or GUID field also if you need only  [Customer Code] field means use this query like this   Select DISTINCT Customer Code from Accessories its working fine